# how to search for line without leading character in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I have a config file of 500+ lines, however, there are only <10 lines uncommented, all teh other lines are commented.

The config file must maintain its integrity, only needed lines should be uncommented, so my question is:

In vim, how do I search for ALL lines with NO leading "#".

Sample portion of the config is like below:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Application(SingletonConfigurable) configuration
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## This is an application.

## The date format used by logging formatters for %(asctime)s
#c.Application.log_datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

## The Logging format template
#c.Application.log_format = '[%(name)s]%(highlevel)s %(message)s'

## Set the log level by value or name.
#c.Application.log_level = 30
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the comments start with `#` in the first column, and you're only interested in non-empty lines, you can search for

```
/^[^#]
```

The `^` anchors the search at the start of each line, `[^#]` is a collection ([`:help /collection`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fcollection)) that is *negated* (via the `^` - same character, different meaning!) to include any character *but* the `#`.

To include empty lines, append `\|^$`. To also accept whitespace in empty lines, `\|^\s*$` instead.

#### Use folding instead of searching

If this is a large file, but you're actually only interested in tiny parts of it, Vim's built-in [`folding`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#folding) can remove all that commented clutter.

You can define a custom [`:help fold-expr`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold-expr) that folds all those lines (`getline()`) that do not match (`!~`) the above regular expression (now enclosed in `'...'` because we need a String expression):

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)!~'^[^#]'
```

Your buffer will then look like this:

```
+-- 10 lines: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c.Application.log_format = '[%(name)s]%(highlevel)s %(message)s'
+--  3 lines: # Set the log level by value or name.
foo.bar = 1
```

You can open and close folds with commands like [`:help zo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#zo).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and simple answer